# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter \u0027filters\u0027

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

When I post my ajax data to my webservice I keep getting this error. I have tried many times and changed my code to return a json string back but it fails every time.All im trying to do is send back the data I have posted so I know it works. I have looked for answers and I have tried other alternatives but im not getting the results here is the error

{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027filters\u0027.","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

jquery:

```
data = [{'Name': 'Acer', 'Count': 1 }, {'Name': 'HP', 'Count': 2 }]
function getProducts(json, pageIndex, pageSize) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/website2/WebServices/GetProducts.asmx/GetProductsAndFilters',
        data: "{'data' : {'filters':" + JSON.stringify(json) + ", 'PageIndex' : " + pageIndex + ", 'PageSize' : " + pageSize +  "}}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (responseText) {
            //alert(responseText.d);
            $('.console').html(responseText.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            //var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            //alert(msg.Message);
            $('.console').html(xhr.responseText)
        }
    });
}
getProducts(data, "0", "2")
```

C#:

```
public class dvals
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
}

public class data
{
    public List<dvals> Filters {get;set;}
    public string PageIndex { get; set; }
    public string PageSize { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public data GetProductsAndFilters(data filters)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    //List<dvals> json = js.Deserialize<List<dvals>>(filters);
    //data json = js.Deserialize<data>(filters);
    var fname = "";
    /*
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        if (filter.Name == "Acer")
        {
            fname = filter.Name;
            break;
        }

    }*/
    return filters; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ASP.NET will handle the JSON [de]serialization for you automatically](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/). Change your server-side method to match the type of data you're passing in from the client-side.

edit: And as Jon pointed out, your data parameter's property key needs to match the WebMethod's input parameter name (this is case-sensitive even).

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<dvals> GetProductsAndFilters(List<dvals> dvals)
{
  // Do what you need to with "filters" here.

  return filters;
}
```

Also, where is the `json` variable in your `JSON.stringify()` call defined? It looks like that should be `data`, given the code you've shown us.

Comment: How do i send back the data I sent to the server. I haven't touched asp.net for ages. could you show so i can get started

Comment: I have updated my code to correct the mistakes but now i get another error which is at the bottom of my code.

Comment: ASP.NET will automatically serialize the return value as JSON if you set the return type correctly (as in my example code above). The error you updated the question with seems like it's the result of not updating your server-side code to remove the double-[de]serialization.

Comment: I did what you said and it worked but now I want to change my data parameter in my ajax call to match my data class in my c# webservice. Im back to getting the same error Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027filters\u0027 how do i fix this i've updated my code so you know what im trying todo.

Comment: Your data parameter to `$.ajax()` should look something like `{"filters":{"Filters":' + JSON.stringify(json) + ', "PageIndex":"' + pageIndex + '", "PageSize":"' + pageSize + '"}'`. Remember that all of the parameters are case-sensitive. As the objects you're passing get more complex, using an approach like this can make things much easier: http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Comment: I got part of it to work it can return the filters but when i change the return type to string return filters.PageIndex i get null why is that and how can i fix it

Comment: I fixed it you had the data string wrong now it works sweet thanks for you're help